# When should I use nodejs and when should I use mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I read many documents about node js and MongoDB. But the regret is that I can't understand when I should use nodejs and when I should use MongoDB. If anyone here who can tell me the details, it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: mongodb is a database, node.js is a server-side scripting language.  two completely different things.

Comment: MongoDb is a database and you would use NodeJs to communicate with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB and NodeJS are two different technologies. MonogDB is a database system which gives you a chance to efficiently store documents in a database and to perform operations like data updates, or to search documents by some criterias.

Otherhand,
NodeJS's responsibilty is especially to execute your application.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a javaScript runtime environment where you can run/execute your javaScript codes meaning it's like the grill to barbeque the turkey and MongoDB on the other hand is totally different technology where you will store your data's in mostly .json format meaning it's like the chilli sauce you can use it to your barbeque or if it's not your likeness you can choose tomato sauce instead. **But if you are going to learn MERN stack then you need to learn both with react.js and express.js**. Home it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two totally different things. MongoDB is a Database while Node JS  is a coding environment. They are related in the sense that you can configure MongoDB in Node JS.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is pretty straightforward.

NodeJs is better for high **I/O intensive** applications and bad for **CPU intensive** applications.

Use MongoDB if you have **no/fewer relationships** among the data you are storing. But if you have a **specific structure** of data that you are storing or there are some **relations** between the data you are storing then go for a relational database.